# How to create a string on the heap in D?

Tags: memory-management, d

I'm writing a trie in D and I want each trie object have a pointer to some data, which has a non-NULL value if the node is a terminal node in the trie, and NULL otherwise. The type of the data is undetermined until the trie is created (in C this would be done with a `void *`, but I plan to do it with a template), which is one of the reasons why pointers to heap objects are desirable.

This requires me to eventually create my data on the heap, at which point it can be pointed to by the trie node. Experimenting, it seems like `new` performs this task, much as it does in C++. However for some reason, this fails with strings. The following code works:

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    string *a;
    string b = "hello";
    a = &b;
    writefln("b = %s, a = %s, *a = %s", b, a, *a);
}
/* OUTPUT:
b = hello, a = 7FFF5C60D8B0, *a = hello
*/
```

However, this fails:

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
    string *a;
    a = new string();
    writefln("a = %s, *a = %s", a, *a);
}
/* COMPILER FAILS WITH:
test.d(5): Error: new can only create structs, dynamic arrays or class objects, not string's
*/
```

What gives? How can I create strings on the heap?

P.S. If anyone writing the D compiler is reading this, the apostrophe in "string's" is a grammatical error.

Comment: "P.S. If anyone writing the D compiler is reading this, the apostrophe in "string's" is a grammatical error."  No, it's intentional.    Should have used a raw string if you wanted it.  auto mystring = \`string's\`;

Answer (score 5):

Strings are always allocated on the heap. This is the same for any other dynamic array (`T[]`, `string` is only an alias to type `immutable(char)[]`).

If you need only one pointer there are two ways to do it:

```
auto str = "some immutable(char) array";
auto ptr1 = &str; // return pointer to reference to string (immutable(char)[]*)
auto ptr2 = str.ptr; // return pointer to first element in string (char*)
```

If you need pointer to empty string, use this:

```
auto ptr = &"";
```

Remember that you can't change value of any single character in string (because they are `immutable`). If you want to operate on characters in string use this:

```
auto mutableString1 = cast(char[])"Convert to mutable."; // shouldn't be used
// or
auto mutableString2 = "Convert to mutable.".dup; // T[].dup returns mutable duplicate of array
```

Generally you should avoid pointers unless you absolutely know what are you doing.

From memory point of view any pointer take 4B (8B for x64 machines) of memory, but if you are using pointers to arrays then, if pointer is not null, there are 12B (+ data in array) of memory in use. 4B if from pointer and 8B are from reference to array, because array references are set of two pointers. One to first and one to last element in array.

Comment: you shouldn't cast from `string` to `char[]` but use `char[]` directly, (you can then upconvert better with `assumeUnique`)

Comment: You are right. Casting from string is potentially dangerous, because of the fact that strings' data are shared between references. Safe method should be with use of `dup` property (added to original answer).

Comment: you might also want to mention idup as well that returns a immutable copy the

Comment: I didn't mentioned `idup` because i am not sure how this work. I know that this call return immutable copy of array, when called for mutable one, but what when called for immutable array? From what i known about D (i only started learning D about one week ago) this call should return not a copy of array, but a new reference, because immutable cannot change his state in his lifetime (by definition of immutable, especially in cases of strings). Two immutable copies are waste of memory and compiler shouldn't allow this, but in that case the second one isn't duplicate anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `string` is just `immutable(char)[]`. So you don't need pointers since `string` is already a dynamic array.

As for creating them, you just do `new char[X]`, not `new string`.

Answer (score 0):

The string contents are on the heap already because strings are dynamic arrays. However, in your case, it is better to use a char dynamic array instead as you require mutability.

```
import std.stdio;

void main() {
  char[] a = null; // redundant as dynamic arrays are initialized to null
  writefln("a = \"%s\", a.ptr = %s", a, a.ptr); // prints: a = "", a.ptr = null
  a = "hello".dup; // dup is required because a is mutable
  writefln("a = \"%s\", a.ptr = %s", a, a.ptr); // prints: a = "hello", a.ptr = 7F3146469FF0
}
```

Note that you don't actually hold the array's contents, but a slice of it. The array is handled by the runtime and it is allocated on the heap.
A good reading on the subject is this article http://dlang.org/d-array-article.html

Answer (score 0):

If you can only use exactly one pointer and you don't want to use the suggestions in Marmyst's answer (`&str` in his example creates a reference to the stack which you might not want, `str.ptr` loses information about the strings length as D strings are not always zero terminated) you can do this:

Remeber that you can think of D arrays (and therefore strings) as a struct with a data pointer and length member:

```
struct ArraySlice(T)
{
    T* ptr;
    size_t length;
}
```

So when dealing with an array the array's content is always on the heap, but the ptr/length combined type is a value type and therefore usually kept on the stack. I don't know why the compiler doesn't allow you to create that value type on the heap using new, but you can always do it manually:

```
import core.memory;
import std.stdio;

string* ptr;

void alloc()
{
    ptr = cast(string*)GC.malloc(string.sizeof);
    *ptr = "Hello World!";
}

void main()
{
    alloc();
    writefln("ptr=%s, ptr.ptr=%s, ptr.length=%s, *ptr=%s", ptr, ptr.ptr, ptr.length, *ptr);
}
```